# Java Layout Manager Advice

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

I've got the idea of how I want my graphics to look but I've been messing around with LayoutManagers for a while and can't seem to find a combination that works well.

Here's the setup:
1 JFrame containing 2 JScrollPanes. ScrollPane1 gets 30% of the JFrame vertical space. ScrollPane2 gets 70% of the JFrame vertical space.

Each JScrollPane has: 1 JLabel centered in the middle at the top of the ScrollPane, 1-4 JButtons centered at the bottom of the scrollpane, and many JCheckBoxes somewhere in the middle of each scrollpane.

Ideally it would look like below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKFgH.jpg

My question is: What layout managers would you use for the JFrame and each JScrollPane?

EDIT: All external toolkits must go through our company's legal division before they can be incorporated into our projects. I would like to stick to internal Java libraries.

EDIT 2: Finished!! Here's the final setup:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/U63Ow.png

What I learned is that it's important to keep compartmentalizing in Java. I was using too few containers for all of my objects hoping they would fit cleanly on the Frame. So I started using way more Panels and Layout Managers and it came out BEAUTIFUL. Looks perfect. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Check out [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/), it's awesome.

Comment: Please be aware that using several panels may often prevent consitent alignment across panels; that may not be a problem in your specific case, but that's often a showstopper in usual applications. Now I try to keep only one panel (ie one layout) for one window/dialog. And I use "higher-level" LayoutManagers, such as DesignGridLayout (which is perfect for most of the windows I have to deal with).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, I would make the content pane of the container a [`JSplitPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html) instance.

The upper half would consist of three layered `JComponent` instances and use the `BoxLayout` manager with a `Y_AXIS` alignment. The top layer would use the `FlowLayout` manager. The middle layer would consist of several juxtaposed `JComponent` instances, where each would use the `BoxLayout`manager with a `Y_AXIS` alignment. And of course, the layer itself would use the `FlowLayout` manager. The bottom layer would consist of several juxtaposed `JComponent` instances and use the `FlowLayout` manager.

The lower half would be the exactly the same as the upper half, and therefore, consider encapsulating all this logic within a single custom component.

For more information, see [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

Comment: I didn't even know about JSplitPane. Reading up about them now and they look awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would be inclined to use MigLayout at pretty much every step.

Comment: All external libraries and toolkits must be approved by my company's legal department before they can be used / linked etc. thanks for this though I will give it a try at home for my own personal use.

Comment: Fair enough, although if you are using Layouts enough to warrant the effort I would recommend starting the approval process.

Comment: This is my first Java visual project. I'm going to test MigLayout when I get home. If I like it (sounds like I will), I'll probably go through the process to get it approved.

Thanks again!